# Python yfinance HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, yfinance

I am new to python, and I am trying to explore `yfinance`. This worked a few months ago, but recently when I tried to execute my code with any `yfinance` modules, I get the following error:

```
import yfinance as yf
stock='AAPL'
stock_yfin=yf.Ticker("{}".format(stock))
# show institutional holders
stock_yfin.institutional_holders

------------>

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Is there a workaround to solve this? I have looked into changing my header and session information, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You should update the question to list the `yfinance` version.

Comment: years later and I have the same problem. It was working some days ago and so it stoped. I guess yfinance is not very stable, as several people alread warned in the foruns. But I don't know what other APIs I can use.

Answer (score 4):

Update your `yfinance` package as:

```
pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

in your virtual environment or global scope whichever you're using.